# Crash in method for creating years array of strings in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a method in my project:

```
func getModels() -> [String] {
    var array:[String] = [ ]
    let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
    let nextYear = year + 1
    for n in 1970...nextYear {
        array.append(String(n))
    }
    return array
}
```

It's a method to return an array on strings starting from `1970` to `current year + 1`.

What could be wrong in this method? Crashlytics is showing a crash on line `for n in 1970...nextYear`. So far the crash occurred 22 times.

Here's the crash log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Haraj                          0x1044d4068 specialized HJUtilitiesInSwift.getModels() + 39 (HJUtilitiesInSwift.swift:39)
1  Haraj                          0x1044f14d8 specialized HJAdPostSelectionViewController.tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:) + 4377973976 (<compiler-generated>:4377973976)
2  Haraj                          0x1044f0508 @objc HJAdPostSelectionViewController.tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:) + 4377969928 (<compiler-generated>:4377969928)
3  UIKitCore                      0x1988ca16c -[UITableView _numberOfRowsInSection:] + 68
4  UIKitCore                      0x1988dcf94 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1948
5  UIKitCore                      0x1988e09f8 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 76
6  UIKitCore                      0x19889d518 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 136
7  UIKitCore                      0x19889c194 -[UITableView reloadData] + 1440
8  Haraj                          0x1044f2120 specialized HJAdPostSelectionViewController.tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) + 4377977120 (<compiler-generated>:4377977120)
9  Haraj                          0x1044f0fc0 @objc HJAdPostSelectionViewController.tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) + 4377972672 (<compiler-generated>:4377972672)
10 UIKitCore                      0x1988a3dc0 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:isCellMultiSelect:] + 1200
11 UIKitCore                      0x1988a38f8 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 108
12 UIKitCore                      0x1988a4100 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 268
13 UIKitCore                      0x1986d1b64 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 316
14 UIKitCore                      0x1986c150c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 232
15 UIKitCore                      0x1986f19f0 _afterCACommitHandler + 76
16 CoreFoundation                 0x19459f06c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
17 CoreFoundation                 0x194599f60 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 420
18 CoreFoundation                 0x19459a3dc __CFRunLoopRun + 968
19 CoreFoundation                 0x194599ce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
20 GraphicsServices               0x19e6e438c GSEventRunModal + 160
21 UIKitCore                      0x1986c8444 UIApplicationMain + 1932
22 Haraj                          0x10440acac main + 15 (main.m:15)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x1944218f0 start + 4
```

While debugging, I did not face the crash.

Comment: Not sure about the crash, but this seems like the sort of thing you could create once and just refer to; `numberOfRowsInSection` is calling this, so you will be calling the function repeatedly.

Comment: I would suspect the crash is coming from `nextYear` being smaller than 1970, which creates an invalid `Range`. This can happen if `Calendar.current` is not Gregorian. I'd suggest experimenting with different `Calendar` types and testing which one causes a crash. Be aware - not all calendars calculate years the same way as the Gregorian does.

Comment: @Paulw11 you are right the method is getting called in cellForIndexAtPath.. method. This indeed in-efficient. But could this be the reason for crash?

Comment: @DávidPásztor okay, we'll change the code to specify the Calendar type as Gregorian. I hope this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect the crash is coming from nextYear being smaller than 1970, which creates an invalid Range. This can happen if Calendar.current is not Gregorian. Be aware - not all calendars calculate years the same way as the Gregorian does.

If you check the year with all calendar types, you can see that a lot of them haven't reached 1970 yet.

```
Calendar(identifier: .buddhist).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 2563
Calendar(identifier: .chinese).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 37
Calendar(identifier: .coptic).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 1736
Calendar(identifier: .ethiopicAmeteAlem).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 7512
Calendar(identifier: .ethiopicAmeteMihret).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 2012
Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 2020
Calendar(identifier: .hebrew).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 5780
Calendar(identifier: .indian).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 1942
Calendar(identifier: .islamic).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 1441
Calendar(identifier: .islamicCivil).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 1441
Calendar(identifier: .islamicTabular).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 1441
Calendar(identifier: .islamicUmmAlQura).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 1441
Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 2020
Calendar(identifier: .japanese).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 2
Calendar(identifier: .persian).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 1399
Calendar(identifier: .republicOfChina).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()) // 109
```

If you want to check against the reference date of 1970, you need to hardcode your `Calendar` to `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)` or `Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)`.

Another possible (probably even better) solution would be to not hardcode 1970 as the start of your range, but rather, generate that dynamically as well, using `Calendar`.

```
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0))
```

This will result in the correct start date being created regardless of what `Calendar` your users' have set on their device.

Comment: Setting the calendar type to Gregorian fixed the issue.